# show select box for each array data group

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array/object output from mysql database:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [lang_id] => 1
            [name] => attr one
            [attribute_group_id] => 1
            [sort_order] => 1
            [in_use] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [lang_id] => 1
            [name] => attr two
            [attribute_group_id] => 1
            [sort_order] => 2
            [in_use] => 0
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [lang_id] => 1
            [name] => attr three
            [attribute_group_id] => 1
            [sort_order] => 3
            [in_use] => 0
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [lang_id] => 1
            [name] => attr four
            [attribute_group_id] => 2
            [sort_order] => 1
            [in_use] => 1
        )

)
```

I need to show select box for each `attribute_group_id` like this:

html:

```
for attribute group id 1

<select name="">
   <option value="1">attr one</option>
   <option value="2">attr two</option>
   <option value="3">attr three</option>
</select>

for attribute group id 2

<select name="">
   <option value="4">attr four</option>
</select>
```

in action,my database output is true and work for this html code? if yes, how do can i generate this html code from my database output?!